# I'm implementing reCaptcha on a very large form (in PHP) -- how can I preserve form data if reCaptcha fails?

Tags: php, forms, recaptcha

Basically I have a gigantic form that would be a pain for anyone to have to re-fill. We have to implement reCaptcha to prevent spam bots.

I want to make it so that if the user enters the reCaptcha incorrectly, their form data is not lost.

The form, reCaptcha lib, and reCaptcha initialization code are in their own file titled `Application.php`. This form POSTs to `application_confirm.php`. `application_confirm` includes another file which processes the form data into an email format and sends it to the admin.

`Application.php` is required on another php page (ironically also titled application.php -- this is the one the user visits, and then the form html is included from the previously mentioned Application.php via `require('content/Application.php')`

I don't really know what I need to do to or where I need to place the captcha validity check -- any help much appreciated!

Comment: make the recaptcha with ajax

Comment: Hi Emilio, would you mind elaborating for me? Thank you.

Comment: @Prefix There is no safe way to send a captcha with AJAX. A sneaky user will just turn JavaScript off.

Comment: @Prefix Hope that answer helps.

Comment: @SweetieBelle yes that is what I was thinking too, I would like to keep it with PHP and if the captcha fails, just redirect back to the form and re-populate the form inputs.

Comment: @Prefix My answer uses JS to preserve form values, this way you keep all the processing overheads on the client side instead of having to store a bunch of dead data (and make a cron to wipe old data).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using JavaScript to improve user experience, but using it to ascertain the outcome of a captcha would be poor design.

Comment: @SweetieBelle if the user turn off javascript, he/she cant get result success from ajax, if(result=='ok'){/* submit form */}else{/* alert('Something wrong') */}...as js is turn off the submit doesnt work...that is the idea???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to store the $_POST data into a $_SESSION instead of a javascript approach.  When the form is submitted, push the $_POST array into a $_SESSION variable. If the recaptcha fails, reload the form with the value from the $_SESSION.  When the form is posted successfully, destroy the session so that if they were to return to the form, it isn't autofilled with old information.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $response = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !$response->is_valid)
    {
        $_SESSION['form'] = $_POST;
    }
    else
    {
        //Handle form processing
    }
?>
```

Set value of input field to value from $_SESSION

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="<?= $_SESSION['form']['email'] ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

### Abuse JavaScript and  `localStorage` for this...

**Requirements**

I'm assuming you have jQuery installed. If not, you'll have to include it on your page or rewrite some of the function for basic JavaScript.

I'm also assuming your user is running a relatively new browser (although you can do much the same thing with cookies, explaining how to set that up is another answer of its own) and doesn't have JavaScript disabled.

**Preserving the form**

First, attach a class of `input-to-store` on every input object you wish to store a value for, then when your user presses the submit button, instead of immediately submitting your form, have it first call a function called `storeValues()` then submit the form:

```
function storeValues() {
    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem('preserve', true);
        $('.input-to-store').each(function() {
            localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val());
        });
    }
}
```

Note: `localStorage` is **not** universally supported, so this method will only support newer browsers (Firefox 3.5+, Chrome 4+, IE 8+). You may wish to have an `else` statement to set these values in cookies if this method isn't supported.

Depending on your form, you may wish to preserve values which aren't stored in the `.val()` accessor. In this case, add another class and do an `.each()` function on each of those too.

**Retrieving values when the form is reloaded**

When the form is loaded, check for preserved values. If found, reload your old values into those fields:

```
if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if(localStorage.getItem('preserve') === true) {
        localStorage.setItem('preserve', false);
        $('.input-to-store').each(function() {
            if(value = localStorage.getItem($(this).attr('id')){
                $(this).val(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Clear `localStorage` when you're done with it**

On your success page (after a successful form submit), you'll want to clear `localStorage` to prevent your application from wasting space on the user's HDD:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

Hope this helps, haven't tested the syntax but it should give you an idea about how to persist data using `localStorage` and get around the dreaded lost form.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having to bring JS into the mix? This is already a fairly complex PHP page and I'd like to keep it to PHP and HTML if at all possible (plus prevent JS/local storage compatibility woes)

Comment: @Prefix Depends how your captcha works. If it submits to your own site, yes, persist `$_POST` or `$_GET` (depending on submit action) into your database, then check for persisted data on refresh, then re-push it into form and clear it if found. **Note: I don't recommend this, it's inefficient and opens up a potential denial of service attack on your database server (user deliberately sends incorrect captcha over and over again). *Do it with `localStorage` and/or cookies if you don't want this vulnerability.***

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to send values using the event onsubmit to the form tag to a page that saves the form values into a session

then basically say you had an input with the name of 'FirstName'

```
<form onsubmitup='PreserverValues();'/>
```

then basically you change all inputs to

```
<input type='text' name='FirstName' value='<?php if isset($_SESSION['FirstName']) echo $_SESSION['FirstName']; ?>'/>
```

Comment: He doesn't want to preserve values on every keypress (1000+ AJAX requests seems like a horribly inefficient way to do it), just on submit. You've not told him how to make that script.

Comment: Right. on submit would be better. I tried to explain it as much as I can because he didn't really supply any code or even the form.

Comment: hi -- the form is far far too long to post here (over 100 parts). I would just like to preserve the entered data on submit so if the captcha returns false, then the form is re-populated and they just ned to change the captcha.

Comment: Are you familiar with AJAX or Javascript?

Comment: Yes I am, not an expert by any means but with some guidance or a nudge in the right direction I could implement something.

Comment: @AliTrixx Post your answers here or take it to chat on SO.

Comment: I can certainly enter the SO chat. It'd probably be best to keep the answering here though (so I can mark correct and get you guys the points you deserve :) )

Answer (score 0):

This is a working example of a recaptcha  preserving form data if reCaptcha fails?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var RecaptchaOptions = {
        lang: 'en',
        theme: 'custom',
        custom_theme_widget: 'recaptcha_widget'
    };
</script>               

<div class="control-group">

    <div id="recaptcha_widget" style="display:none">

        <input type="text" id="recaptcha_response_field" name="recaptcha_response_field" class="required"/>

        <div id="recaptcha_image"></div>

        <div class="recaptcha_only_if_incorrect_sol" style="color:red">Incorrect please try again</div>

        <div><a href="javascript:Recaptcha.reload()">Get another CAPTCHA code</a></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=YOURKEY"></script>

    <noscript>
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=YOURKEY" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
    <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">
    </noscript>                                                 

    <?php
    require_once('captcha/recaptchalib.php');
    $publickey = "YOURKEY"; // you got this from the signup page
    echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
    ?>      

</div><!-- control grp captcha -->
```